# converting excel formula to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel

Problem: I am not getting any errors when I run the code, however I am getting a different sum and I can't figure out why? the best I can gather is the function is on point until it reaches the first Math.pow once it passes through it's sum is different any idea why? is there a better way?

Excel formula

```
=0.25 / (    LOG(
        $I$6 / 3.7 + 5.74 / G18 ^ 0.9
    ) ) ^ 2 


Sum of excel formula is 0.0186
```

My JavaScript

```
var test = function() {
  var num = 0.00006 / 3.7;
  var num2 = Math.pow(90068.45754973275, 0.9);
  var num3 = 5.74 / num2;
  var num4 = num + num3;
  var num5 = Math.log(num4);
  var num6 = Math.pow(num5, 2);
  var num7 = 0.25 / num6;
  return +num7.toFixed(4);
};


Before .toFixed(4) sum is 0.0035080344556698015
After sum is 0.0035
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough rep points yet or I would. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript LOG is the natural logarithm (so base e), Excel's LOG function is the base-10 logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

Num3 is wrong. It should be inverted :

```
var num3 = 5.74 / num2;
```

Also num4 should be num + num3 :

```
var num4 = num + num3
```

Comment: I'm still not getting the right sum thou, what I'm getting now is                               0.0035080344556698015

Comment: What if you replace "+num7" by just num7 ?

Comment: Are you looking for base 2 log, for ln, or for base 10 log ? Maybe these are ninth the same logs. Try specifying the base in both cases

Comment: not placing the + in front of the "num7" will log a string an not a number.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested the answer is Math.log10();